# What am I doing wrong here (CURL), no matter what I try it returns empty/null

Tags: php, curl, reddit

```
$url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/{mysubreddit}/new.json";
$fields = "sort=new";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data);
```

{mysubreddit} is whatever subreddit I wanna check.  It works fine to just grab that url via postman, or even in the browser.  But when I use PHP/CURL, it returns empty.  I've tried replacing the URL, with another URL to another site, and it works fine, so the curl part is working fine.

Is there something with reddit that I have to set? headers?  or explicitly tell it for JSON? Or what?

I thought it might have to do with POST, but I tried GET to, still empty/null.

```
$url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/{mysubreddit}/new.json?sort=new";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

That doesnt work either

Comment: The url is redirecting to https. Change your url to https or add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); to your curl request.

Comment: worked with my all purpose curl function... https://gist.github.com/Pamblam/1919100f017e27548a85ee695120a3a4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Awesome, this helped me in my case, running a regular curl request gives 301 error, which means the server probably offers another redirect, which curl is not following, adding that line of code makes ur request follow any redirect offered by the serve.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, reddit is sending you a 302 redirect to https.  You would be able to see that by examining the headers returned by [`curl_getinfo()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php).

Enabling redirect following, as sorak describes, will work.  However, it's not a good solution - you will make two HTTP requests on every single API call.  This is a completely unnecessary waste of network and increases the execution time of your script.  Instead, just change the url that you're requesting to be from `https://www.reddit.com/` in the first place.